# what happen to phonegap 3.4, 3.3 command line interface?

Tags: cordova

I used to use phonegap prior to version 3.3 command line interface as mentioned in the docs below:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.2.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface

however after installing phonegap 3.4 the phonegap command line have been replaced by cordovas's as mentioned here:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface

I try to run cordova CLI but it does not exist. do I miss something ?

My question is  can I still use the old phonegap command line as mentioned in the doc phonegap 3.2 ? is there any impact if I still use phonegap 3.2 for phonegap 3.4 ?

If I follow the doc mentioned in phonegap 3.4 do I have to install cordova along with phonegap ?

Comment: You can continue using phonegap CLI if you have phonegap installed

Comment: is there any consequence if i use the phonegap command instead of cordova command in 3.4 ?

Comment: No, they are basically the same. Phonegap is built over cordova and adds the phonegap build service if you don't have the SDKs installed

Answer (score 2):

Sorry i had to update my answer because after phonegap 3.3 you have to install Apache Cordova.

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
```

and use `cordova` instead of `phonegap`. for example: `cordova platform add ios`.

Comment: cordova command is not recognized after installing phonegap. I do understand the difference between phonegap and cordova. what I really confuse is the old phonegap commands are not mentioned any more in phonegap 3.4.

Comment: commands are not mentioned but it will work. Read the above post.

Answer (score 1):

The software underlying PhoneGap is Apache Cordova.The software was previously called just "PhoneGap", then "Apache Callback". Apache Cordova is open source software.

PhoneGap is a distribution of Apache Cordova. You can think of Apache Cordova as the engine that powers PhoneGap, similar to how WebKit is the engine that powers Chrome or Safari.

Over time, the PhoneGap distribution may contain additional tools that tie into other Adobe services, which would not be appropriate for an Apache project.

Currently, the only difference is in the name of the download package and will remain so for sometime.

Late last year, Adobe/Nitobi donated the PhoneGap codebase to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) for enhancement. The document which you mentioned in the first link http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.2.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface
is prepared before providing to Apache Software Foundation.

And the second link is prepared after enhancement.http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface.

This has been noticed by most of the peoples, while using phonegap 3.3 version.

So you can use phonegap or cordova. Few futures will defer, as advised in phonegap site, we should go with cordova.

Hope you are clear.

Comment: adding reference material would be great.

Comment: Refer this link http://phonegap.com/2012/03/19/phonegap-cordova-and-what%E2%80%99s-in-a-name/

Answer (score 0):

Ya you can use any version of PhoneGap 2.9.0 and Above. The Cordova have just updated 3.4.0 version, which have some issues.

You can see in below Image, we've **STAGING** folder inside that the main www directory exists, where we have to implement our Code.

[image]

You can uninstall Cordova 3.4.0 by this command **sudo npm uninstall -g cordova@3.4.0**

Install Specific version of Cordova by this command **sudo npm install -g cordova@2.9.0**

**Finally, i would like to summarize that, there will be no issue in working in updated or previous version.**

Comment: @now all phoneGap command work with Cordova. All command remain same just replace phone gap with Cordova